# VS Code - LaTeX Workshop - Typesetting a LaTeX file with extension ".md" instead of ".tex"

Tags: vscode

For a reason difficult to explain, I need to be able to typeset a LaTeX file with a ".md" extension. (No, I can't change it into ".tex".)

pdlatex (and TeXShop) allows this.

Is it possible in VS Code - LaTeX Workshop?

Many TIA